# Rename parameters for a request in NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

I am building a simple proxy for sending two get requests to a data provider OpenWeatherMap. According to its documentation, if I want to get a current weather, I need to send a request with a parameter `q`. Currently I make my requests from a frontend part using Axios library and I indicate this `q` parameter there. But I want to make it more readable and send requests with a parameter `cityName`. How do I change the parameter name in my NET Core part of the application?

Here is what I do in my HttpClient:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync( "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather" + pathAndQuery.Replace( apiEndpoint, "" ) + "&appid=ggggg" );
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
    await context.Response.WriteAsync( result );
}
```

Comment: I don't see the parameter q anywhere in your code. Are you missing something? All you do is return the result here

Comment: No, I didn't miss anything. As I mentioned, I send this parameter in Axios request (in the frontend part of the app). My frontend looks at the variable `apiEndpoint` which I use in the backend request. So if there is a match, OpenWeatherMap provider get the `q` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a method like that:

```
public const string Endpoint = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather";
public async void GetWeatherBytCityName(string cityName)
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        var query = $"?q={cityName}";
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync( $"{Endpoint}{query}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like something I needed! I will check it in a couple of hours and answer if it worked out or not. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't. I got lots of errors in my console. One of them was ' modifier 'public' is not valid for this item' after I was trying to add the second line of your solution.

Comment: @OlgaB You can't have a modifier in a method. In C#, there is no such thing as method in method. For further help, please post the full method.